# I'm trying to make a comparison between two variables that are numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a game, and once the two scores match I want it to show "You won" but I can't get the two scores to compare.

I tried the parseInt method and .val method, no go.

```
var numberFour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 10);
$("#four").on("click", function() {

   playerScore = playerScore + numberFour
   $("#score").text(playerScore);
})
console.log(numberFour);


for (var i = 0; i < 121; i++) {
    var goalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 9); 
    $("#goal").text(goalNumber);
    };



if (playerScore == goalNumber) {
     console.log("You won!");
}
else {
    console.log("You suck!")
}
```

Comment: what is `playerScore` initialised to?

Comment: Have you declared playerScore outside the onclick method you created for '#four'? Don't forget to close that function with a semi-colon. It looks like you're using the correct comparison operator. When are you calling this if-else statement? Is it inside the document being loaded? Do you have it set to run on a condition or event listener?

Comment: why are you looping 121 times to create `goalNumber` - it'll only be the last value created in that loop

Comment: playerscore is updated on click ... but the comparison is only run once

Comment: var randomNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
var wins = 0
var losses = 0
var playerScore = 0
var goalNumber = 0

Here are my variables. I have three other onclick methods above, didn't need repeating.

Comment: So how would I get it to keep comparing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're running through such a large loop for goalNumber, but try this code out. I changed your loop so you're not re-declaring goalNumber 120+ times and put your comparison inside your onclick call so it's continuously called every time you update your playerScore. I don't know how you've got your game setup, but I think it'll be tough for them to ever be equal when you're using random numbers.

Also, it helps to know when you're calling portions of your code. Omitting event handlers makes it difficult to debug your code. How else do we know when things are being used?

```
var playerScore = 0;
var goalNumber = 0;
var numberFour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 10);

for (var i = 0; i < 121; i++) {
    goalNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 9); 
    $("#goal").text(goalNumber);
};

$("#four").on("click", function() {
   playerScore += numberFour;
   $("#score").text(playerScore);

   if (playerScore == goalNumber) {
        console.log("You won!");
   }
   else {
       console.log("You suck!")
   }
});
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Mind accepting this as the best answer? :)